# Caffe accuracy increases too fast

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, face-detection

I'm doing a AlexNet fine tuning for face detection following this: [link](https://github.com/guoyilin/FaceDetection_CNN)

The only difference with the link is that I am using another dataset (facescrub and some images from imagenet as negative examples).

I noticed the accuracy increasing too fast, in 50 iterations it goes from 0.308 to 0.967 and when it is about 0.999 I stop the training and use the model using the same python script as the above link.

I use for testing an image from the dataset and the result is nowhere near good, [test image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDAFF.jpg). As you can see the box in the faces is too big (and the dataset images are tightly cropped), not to mention the box not containing a face.

My solver and train_val files are exactly the same, only difference is batch sizes and max iter size.

Comment: I noticed that my data set contains way more positive than negative examples, can this be the reason of that fast accuracy increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that my dataset has way more face examples than non-face examples. I tried the same setup with the same number of positive and negative examples and now the accuracy increases slower.